# Выход за пределы системы координат в Div html

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка, координаты

Поблема состоит в том, что при выходе за пределы вниз и вправо, скролл появляется.
А при выходе влево и вверх - его нет. А он нужен (код ниже можно запустить и проверить)

```js
$(function () {
    $("#draggable3").draggable({});
});
```

```css
.generic-container {
 height: 95vh;
  width: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
 background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative; 
 
}


#draggable3{
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vh;
  background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 28%;
 top: 28%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="generic-container">
    <div id='draggable3' class="draggable">
        
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Ограничивать передвижение параметром - containment: 'parent' НЕ ПОДХОДИТ!

Comment: я тут логическую часть придумал, а как это сделать пока хз)
возможно ли видимую часть generic-container показывать чуть дальше чем координаты 0х0
Тоесть: Сейчас блок generic-container построен таким образом что видимая часть занимает от 0х0px до 1920х1080px(примерно) возможно ли отображать к примеру с 500х500px до 2420х1580px - тем самым работать мы будем там, а обработку выхода влево и вверх опишу на Jquery.

Comment: Так вам проще самому сделать свой скролл-бар вместо стандартных

Comment: @Crantisz то-есть создать див с position:absolute. Еrо видимую часть реrулировать самим. И показывать свой скроллбар коrда нужно при этом увеличивая див в нужную сторону? Лоrика верная?

Comment: Типа того, контейнер `overflow: hidden`